# Nodered - join message sequence and return as buffer

Tags: sorting, sequence, node-red

I currently work on a flow that would convert text into speech by using OpenAI's TTS API.
The problem I currently face is within the join node, that simply wont join the data in the desired way.

This is the part of the flow:
[image: message flow in node red]

The split node returns a message sequence with "msg.parts" property set. I then convert the text of each message into a mp3 file (buffer) and want to join the buffers at the end. That's the part that doesn't work as expected.

When I use "automatic" mode in the join node the result is no buffer - instead the payloads are joined as strings.

When I use "manual" mode to return a buffer the join node ignores the msg.parts.index order and the messages are (probably) joined with the wrong order.

I tried to use a sort node before join but that failed - probably due to misconfiguration.

The response of the http request still has the msg.parts information:
[image: response of http request]

Here's the code of the split text node:

```
let maxChunkSize = 4096;
let text = msg.payload;
let chunks = [];
let startIndex = 0;

while (startIndex < text.length) {
    let endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + maxChunkSize, text.length);
    // Ensure we end on a full word by searching for the last space within the limit
    if (endIndex < text.length) {
        while (text[endIndex] !== ' ' && endIndex > startIndex) {
            endIndex--;
        }
    }
    // If no space was found, just split at the maxChunkSize
    if (endIndex === startIndex) {
        endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + maxChunkSize, text.length);
    }
    chunks.push(text.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim());
    startIndex = endIndex;
}

msg.payload = chunks;
return msg; // Return as an array of messages to be compatible with the Split node.
```

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77738578/edit) the question to include the (text, not image) of the code in the "create voice request" function node. Need to check you are not dropping the split/join data. Also are you sure you can just concatenate MP3 files?

Comment: I already verified I can concatenate mp3 buffer data - works like charm, the only problem is the order. The msg.part information is still present but the manual join seems to ignore it - see the screenshot with the output of the http request: https://cloud.kw.at/s/XKHzHPdTs78MRKX

Comment: You have nested `msg.parts` which means you have an more split nodes than you are showing here.